# I am trying to install espeak on python in vscode

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, python-wheel, espeak

```
PS C:\Users\lukas\glados-tts-main\glados-tts-main> pip install python-espeak 
Collecting python-espeak
  Using cached python-espeak-0.6.3.tar.gz (9.1 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: python-espeak
  Building wheel for python-espeak (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\espeak
      copying espeak\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\espeak
      running build_ext
      building 'espeak.core' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\espeak
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpespeak/espeakmodulecore.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\espeak/espeakmodulecore.obj
      espeakmodulecore.cpp
      espeak/espeakmodulecore.cpp(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'espeak/speak_lib.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-espeak
  Running setup.py clean for python-espeak
Failed to build python-espeak
Installing collected packages: python-espeak
  Running setup.py install for python-espeak ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for python-espeak did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\lukas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\espeak
      copying espeak\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\espeak
      running build_ext
      building 'espeak.core' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\espeak
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpespeak/espeakmodulecore.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\espeak/espeakmodulecore.obj
      espeakmodulecore.cpp
      espeak/espeakmodulecore.cpp(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'espeak/speak_lib.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> python-espeak

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
PS C:\Users\lukas\glados-tts-main\glados-tts-main>
```

I'm not able to get espeak installed

I have tried to install espeak through differnent means, all of them successful, but when I ran the code, it gave me "RuntimeError: espeak not installed on your system". I'm hoping that this version of espeak will solve my issue, but when I tried `pip install python-espeak` it just gives me the error.

Comment: It looks like you haven't instead espeak itself. The `python-espeak` package is presumably just a set of Python bindings.

Comment: Indeed, per the package's README: _"Requires espeak and its libraries to be installed espeak/speak_lib.h should be in your include path somewhere."_

Comment: But in that case it's still weird. I have allready downloaded espeak from https://sourceforge.net/projects/espeak If that is all I need to do then shouldn't it just work. Neither the code nor the the command "pip install python-espeak" works